# Receiving pictures directly in Pidgin over Facebook

Tags: facebook, pidgin, facebook-chat

I am using Pidgin for the Facebook chat. Every time someone sends a picture or a file in Facebook, I just receive an annoying link in Pidgin. Is there any plugin to display the picture in Pidgin or receive the picture as a file?

The links look like this:

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/<looks_random_generated>.jpg?oh=<looks_random_generat>&oe=<looks_random_generated>&__gda__=<looks_random_generated>
```

I imagine it like a plugin which replaces a link like this with a displayed picture.